# getLaunchIntentForPackage is null for apps

Tags: android, gridview, launcher, package-managers

1. I'm building installed apps in alert grid view. and I am selecting
   some favorite apps and adding into another grid view after that if
   I select any app from new gridview app its getting Intent value (**getLaunchIntentForPackage**) is null.

   ```
   quick_links_alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
               List<String> mArrayProducts = clad.getCheckedItems();
               final QuickLinksGridViewAdaptor selected_apps = new QuickLinksGridViewAdaptor(HomeActivity.this, mArrayProducts);
               gv_shortcut.setAdapter(selected_apps);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected Items-->:"+mArrayProducts,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               PackageManager pm = HomeActivity.this.getPackageManager();
               Intent quick_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
               final List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(quick_intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
               gv_shortcut.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                       final String packageName = list.get(position).activityInfo.packageName;
                       Intent PackageManagerIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
                       if (PackageManagerIntent != null) {
                           startActivity(PackageManagerIntent);
                       }
                       else {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NULL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                   }
               });
           }
   In my grid view 8 applications are available.If I click any application its PackageManagerIntent is getting null and 1 and 3 position application its always open google search engine and player application is opening.
   ```

Comment: I am getting selected app name is getting perfect.I could  not able to understand selected app is not opening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem:

```
String s = mArrayProducts.get(position).getPackageName();
Intent PackageManagerIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(s); NULL
startActivity(PackageManagerIntent);
```